# Open Numeric keyboard on ASPX Wep page´(sample.aspx) when calling from Iphone and android mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, html

Those who marked this as duplicate please review and answer me ! Because here my scenario is totally different from other ! I'm not having a HTML website! I'm having ASPX web page application! So if I set type="number" or "tel" its not running! Because there is no such attribute in ASPX page  tag. I'm using  only allowed! So those previous answers for HTML page only I can use type="number" or "tel". Please try in ur local environment. Because try this code `<input type="number" runat="server" id="numberonly"/> or <input type="tel" runat="server" id="numberonly"/>` but this will work if we didn't use runat="server" attribute like this

```
<input type="number" id="numberonly"/>
```

But I want with runat="server" because I'm taking those parameter to back-end like getting value of field like .value ! So please help me to do this in client side itself.

I have searched a lot of content to show only numeric keyboard, when they call my aspx web page from a android or a iPhone or both... In HTML5 i have the type attribute number to achieve this but my problem is I'm having a mobile site page on ASPX web page.

The code `<input type="text" id="txtnumber" value="Numberonly" pattern="[0-9]*"  />`
Was not working! So i want to define a attribute number so that i can use that on `<input type="number"` please can any one help? I already tried `type="tel"` also!

Comment: Try `<input type="number" name="txtnumber" min="1" max="5">` BUT do not think you can do that on a website. Try to at least make a javascript for the field to accept only numbers.

Comment: We can set a type attribute dynamically by using javascript for input type=number. code will be look like this <input id="txtnumber" runat="server /> use javascript function <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >           function setTypeNumeric() {
             
             document.getElementById('<%=txtnumber .ClientID%>').type = 'number';
         }
         $(document).ready(function () {
             setTypeNumeric();
         });
    </script>   I've answered my own question but because of its marked as duplicate i cant get reputation. Thanks guys!!!